# jQuery dropdown toggle find active li and keep the dropdown open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got some trouble with a custom dropdown toggle.

The menu looks like this in HTML and I do not have the option to edit the code for that so I have to solve it with css/jQuery:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Link"</a></li>   <-- when this is active it has class="active"
    <li><a href="">Link"</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link"</a></li>
    <li class="">                   <-- this is always empty
        <span>Title</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Link</a></li>   <-- this is currently active
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm a bit afraid to ask but here is what I've got:

```
$('.menu li[class=""] span').click(function() {
    const self = $(this).parent();
    self.toggleClass("menu-open");
});

if($('.menu li[class=""]').find('li.active').length !== 0){
    $(this).addClass("menu-open");
}
```

The first function which actually works pretty well checks if there is a `li` with a `class=""` as this indicates it has a submenu. Clicking the `span` in the `li` toggles the class `menu-open` which results in either having the menu open or collapsed.

Now I would like to keep the menu open when I'm on a page that's in the submenu. If that's the case the `li` in the sub `ul` is active, the parent `li` is not.

Unfortunately that doesn't work. I also tried different approaches such as `hasClass`, `children` but none of it worked either. I pinpointed the issue mostly to:

```
$(this).addClass("menu-open");
```

as it seems that `$(this)` was never found. If I change $(this) to $('body') for example and add a hide(), I clearly see that it works because I get a blank page :)

Any advise on what the issue is would be much appreciated as I nearly gave up now.

```js
$(function() {

    $('.menu li[class=""] span').click(function() {
        const self = $(this).parent();
        self.toggleClass("menu-open");
    });

    if($('.menu li[class=""]').find('li.active').length !== 0){
        $(this).addClass("menu-open");
 }

});
```

```css
.menu{width:200px}
ul{list-style-type:none}
li{background:#ccc;margin:2px}
span{display:block}
.menu li[class=""]{
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.menu-open{
    height:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="">
      <span>Title</span>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a><li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a><li>
    <li class="">
      <span>Title</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a runnable code.

Comment: I've added a sample code to my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `each` operator that JQuery provides.

It's something like this:

```
$('.menu li').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('li.active').length !== 0) {
    $(this).addClass('menu-open');
  }
});
```

In your case, the context that is using the `this` expression doesn't represent the selector you tried to use in `if`.

in the example using `each`, the `this` expression that is inside the function represents the element being interacted represented by the selector.

Comment: I noticed I had to change $(this).addClass('active') as well before you edited it. Your solutions works perfectly fine - thanks a lot :) (and thank you for explaining why!)